# Gerunds, before or after names?

Tags: gerunds

Consider the following:

> The furniture makers in those early decades of the 1600’s were known as “joiners,”
> for the primary method of constructing furniture, at least among the English of this
> time, was that of mortise-and-tenon joinery.

I wonder, what is the grammatical function of "constructing" in the sentence? Is it grammatically correct? Because, I think when we use gerunds, we have to put the name before the gerund: "furniture constructing" 
If it was like "furniture construction", would it change the meaning?

Answer (score 2):

It is fully grammatically correct since gerunds can take direct objects. In your example the "furniture" is a direct object of a gerund "constructing".

Regarding using "furniture construction" instead - I think both variants would mean basically the same, but probably native speakers can find some semantic subtleties between them.